# C++ assignment on ABCs, inheritance and virtual functions, trying to figure out a segfault and more

Tags: c++, inheritance, segmentation-fault, virtual, abstract-class

I have a C++ assignment in which we have to implement some classes that inherit from an ABC called Object. Each Object has a specific ID.

We have a class String (using an std::string for its implementation) which is an Object and will be used instead of std::string.

Also we have a PlaneComponent ABC that is an Object and has a datamember "String description".
Another class is PassengerCompartment which is a PlaneComponent and has a datamember that is a pointer to another PassengerCompartment (like an inner PassengerCompartment).

We have a function "clone" that returns an Object* to the cloned Object.
I create a PassengerCompartment object called "test" in main and an Object* ptr and clone the "test" object.
Then I checked if these Objects(PassengerCompartments) are equal and got "not equal" which is not correct.
So I started checking the equal functions.
The problem is that when I call String::equal and in its body I have this command:

```
cout << ((String*)other_object)->get_string() << endl;
```

(get_string() is an accessor to the std::string of Class String returning an std::string)
**I get a segfault:**

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0xb76e2d88 in std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string () from /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6
```

**This is the output of bt full at gdb:**

```
(gdb) bt full
#0  0xb767ed88 in std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string () from /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6
No symbol table info available.
#1  0x0804bb10 in String::get_string (this=0xbfdb5560) at objects.h:55
No locals.
#2  0x0804b2de in String::equal (this=0xbfdb5568, other_object=0xbfdb5560) at     objects.cpp:129
No locals.
#3  0x0804b5a5 in PlaneComponent::equal (this=0xbfdb5560, other_object=0xbfdb5560) at objects.cpp:191
No locals.
#4  0x0804ba3a in PassengerCompartment::equal (this=0xbfdb5560, other_object=0xbfdb5560) at objects.cpp:372
result = false
#5  0x080492b4 in main () at main.cpp:47
anew = {<Object> = {_vptr.Object = 0x804c008, id = 1}, the_string = {static npos = 4294967295, 
_M_dataplus = {<std::allocator<char>> = {<__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<char>> = {<No data fields>}, <No data fields>}, _M_p = 0x804f014 "A Class"}}}
test = {<PlaneComponent> = {<Object> = {_vptr.Object = 0x804bfc8, id = 2}, description = {<Object> = {_vptr.Object = 0x804c008, id = 1}, 
  the_string = {static npos = 4294967295, 
    _M_dataplus = {<std::allocator<char>> = {<__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<char>> = {<No data fields>}, <No data fields>}, 
      _M_p = 0x804f014 "A Class"}}}}, inner_PassengerCompartment = 0x0}
ptr = (class Object *) 0x804f020
```

**And this is the output of valgrind:**

```
==14233==  Bad permissions for mapped region at address 0x804C004
==14233==    at 0x40CFD88: std::string::string(std::string const&) (in /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.9)
==14233==    by 0x804BB0F: String::get_string() (objects.h:55)
==14233==    by 0x804B2DD: String::equal(Object const*) (objects.cpp:129)
==14233==    by 0x804B5A4: PlaneComponent::equal(Object const*) (objects.cpp:191)
==14233==    by 0x804BA39: PassengerCompartment::equal(Object const*) (objects.cpp:372)
==14233==    by 0x80492B3: main (main.cpp:47)
```

**In String::equal(Object* other_object), in gdb I get this:**

```
(gdb) print *this
$1 = {<Object> = {_vptr.Object = 0x804bfa8, id = 1}, the_string = {static npos = 4294967295, 
_M_dataplus = {<std::allocator<char>> = {<__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<char>> = {<No data fields>}, <No data fields>}, _M_p = 0x804f014 "A Class"}}}

(gdb) print *other_object 
$2 = {_vptr.Object = 0x804bf68, id = 2}
```

So as I see it Object* ptr is only an object and not a PassengerCompartment as well.

So the problem is with the clone function? (in this function "Object* PassengerCompartment::clone(void)" I have this:

```
return new PassengerCompartment(*this);
```

What am I doing wrong? I really can't figure it out. Maybe the copy constructors?
Please tell me which other info you would like me to include!

**Thank you in advance for your help!**

**Some extra notes:**
Object* Object::clone() is pure virtual.

**[This is the code of the equal functions and the copy constructors](http://pastebin.com/aLLAmACd)**
**[These are the source files as asked](http://www.2shared.com/file/gOdwma9c/oop_assignment3.html) |||[Mirror here](http://www.mediafire.com/?pp234buwt254ec3)**

Comment: The relevant code would help, especially if you could condense it down to a small, self-contained example.

Comment: Just added the code at pastebin! "if you could condense it down to a small, self-contained example", if it is not clear from the code that I've posted, I will try and do that, but with the code being short in length I don't think it can be condensed even more :S

Comment: I'd prefer you un-condense it. Show the whole thing.

Comment: @chris i've founded something, see my answer

Comment: @stinky472: These are the source files (http://www.2shared.com/file/gOdwma9c/oop_assignment3.html)

Answer (score 2):

After examining the full source code, it's got many problems. But there are three main lines that are actually buggy, and the rest come down to const-correctness.

A. In PassengerCompartment::equal, you are not returning anything. You need to *return result;* The lack of a return value in a function that doesn't return void is going to invoke undefined behavior.

B.

```
cout << dynamic_cast<const String&>(*other_object).get_string() << endl;
```

You're attempting to cast a PlaneComponent reference to a String reference. PlaneComponent does not inherit String anywhere in its hierarchy. I suspect what you meant to do is:

```
cout << other_object->toString().get_string() << endl;
```

C.

```
if ( the_string == ((String*)other_object)->the_string)
```

Same issue as B. PlaneComponent does not implement the String interface, and thus cannot be cast to it. That is an illegal cast and would invoke undefined behavior.

The rest of your problems come down to const-correctness. You're being good about const-correctness when it comes to function parameters. For instance, the equal method does not modify the object we're comparing, so you take it as a read-only pointer: good. However, you are not doing this at all when it comes to defining methods as read-only. For example:

```
virtual bool equal(const Object* other_object);
```

Should be:

```
virtual bool equal(const Object* other_object) const;
```

Without doing this consistently, the corrections above will invoke compiler errors. Here is the full source after corrections:

```
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// objects.h
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class String;

class Object
{
  private:
    int id;
  public:
    //constructors and destructor
    Object(void);
    Object(const Object& object_);
    virtual ~Object(void);

    //general functionality
    virtual bool equal(const Object* other_object) const { return (id == other_object->id); }
    bool identical(const Object& other_object) const { return (this == &other_object); }
    virtual String toString(void) const = 0;
    virtual Object* clone(void) const = 0;

    //accessor
    int get_id(void) const {return id;} 
};


///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// objects.cpp
class String : public Object
{
  private:
    std::string the_string;
  public:
    //constructors, assignment operator and destructor
    String(void);
    String(std::string given);
    String(const String& given);
    String& operator=(const String& given);
    virtual ~String(void);
    //String(const std::string& given) 

    //general functionality
    int length(void);
    void clear(void);
    char& at(int pos);
    void updateAT(int pos, std::string given);
    void concat(const String& given);
    void print(void);

    virtual String toString(void) const;
    virtual Object* clone(void) const;
    virtual bool equal(const Object* other_object) const;


    //accessor
    std::string get_string(void) const { std::cout << the_string << std::endl; return the_string; }
};


///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
class PlaneComponent : public Object
{
  private:
    String description;
  public:
    //constructor and destructor
    PlaneComponent(const String& describe_it);
    PlaneComponent(const PlaneComponent& given);
    virtual ~PlaneComponent(void);

    //general functionality
    virtual void ready_check(void) = 0;
    //virtual void process(void) = 0; 
    virtual String toString(void) const = 0;
    virtual bool equal(const Object* other_object) const = 0;
    virtual Object* clone(void) const = 0;

    //accessor
    String get_description(void) const { return description; }
};


///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
class PassengerCompartment : public PlaneComponent
{
  private:
    PassengerCompartment* inner_PassengerCompartment;
  public:
    //constructor and destructor
    PassengerCompartment(const String& description_given);
    PassengerCompartment(const PassengerCompartment& given);
    //constructors for the inner passenger_compartment
    PassengerCompartment(const String& description_given, bool for_innerPC);
    PassengerCompartment(const PassengerCompartment& given, bool for_innerPC);
    virtual ~PassengerCompartment(void);

    //general functionality
    //void more_space(const String& inner_description);
    virtual String toString(void) const;
    virtual void ready_check(void);
    virtual Object* clone(void) const;
    virtual bool equal(const Object* other_object) const;


    //accessor
    PassengerCompartment* get_inner_PassengerCompartment(void);
};


///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////




#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
Object::Object(void)
{
    cout << "Object just created!" << endl;
    static int id_ = 1;
    id = id_;
    id_++;
}


Object::Object(const Object& object_) 
{ 
    id = object_.id; 
    cout << "Copy of Object just created!" << endl;
}


Object::~Object(void) 
{ 
    id = -1; 
    cout << "Object to be destroyed!" << endl;
}
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
String::String(void) 
{ 
    cout << "String just created!" << endl;
}


String::String(std::string given) 
{ 
    the_string = given;
    cout << "String just created!" << endl;
}


String::String(const String& given) : Object(given) 
{
    the_string = given.the_string;
    cout << "Copy of String just created!" << endl;
}


String::~String(void) 
{ 
    the_string.empty(); 
    cout << "String to be destroyed!" << endl; 
}


String& String::operator=(const String& given)
{
    if (&given != this)
    {
        this->the_string = given.the_string;
    }
    return *this;
}

////////////////////////////////////////////
int String::length(void)
{
    return the_string.length();
}


void String::clear(void)
{
    the_string.clear();
}


char& String::at(int pos)
{
    return the_string.at(pos);
}


void String::updateAT(int pos, string given)
{
    the_string.replace(pos, 1, given);
}


void String::concat(const String& given)
{
    the_string.append(given.the_string);
}


void String::print(void)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < the_string.length(); i++)
    {
        cout << the_string.at(i);
    }
    cout << endl;
}
////////////////////////////////////////////
String String::toString(void) const
{
    ostringstream resultstream; 
    resultstream << "String with content: <<" << the_string
                 << ">> and id: " << Object::get_id();
    String result( resultstream.str() );
    return result;
}


Object* String::clone(void) const
{
    return new String(*this);
}


bool String::equal(const Object* other_object) const
{
    cout <<"the_string: " << endl;
    //this->print(); 
    cout << this->get_string() << endl;
    cout <<"other_object the_string: " << endl;
    cout << other_object->toString().get_string() << endl;
    //cout << dynamic_cast<String*>(other_object)->get_string() << endl;
    //cout << ((String*)other_object)->get_string() << endl; 
    //cout << ((String*)other_object)->the_string << endl;
    //((PassengerCompartment*)other_object)->get_description().print();
    //check if strings are the same
    if ( the_string == other_object->toString().get_string())
    {
        //check id
        if ( Object::equal(other_object) )
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
    else
        return false;
}
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
PlaneComponent::PlaneComponent(const String& describe_it) : description(describe_it)
{ 
    cout << description.get_string() << endl;
    cout << "PlaneComponent just created!" << endl;
}


PlaneComponent::PlaneComponent(const PlaneComponent& given) : Object(given), description(given.description)
{ 
    cout << description.get_string() << endl;
    cout << "PlaneComponent just created!" << endl; 
}


PlaneComponent::~PlaneComponent(void) 
{ 
    cout << "PlaneComponent to be destroyed!" << endl; 
}


/*PlaneComponent::PlaneComponent(const String& describe_it)
{
    description = describe_it;
    cout << "PlaneComponent just created!" << endl; 
}*/


////////////////////////////////////////////
bool PlaneComponent::equal(const Object* other_object) const
{
    cout << "------------------" << endl;
    cout << "------------------" << endl;
    cout << "------------------" << endl;
    cout << "------------------" << endl;
    cout << "--------PlaneComponent::equal----------" << endl;
    this->get_description().print();
    dynamic_cast<const PlaneComponent*>(other_object)->get_description().print();
    cout << "--------PlaneComponent::equal----------" << endl;
    cout << "------------------" << endl;
    cout << "------------------" << endl;
    cout << "------------------" << endl;
    cout << "------------------" << endl;
    //check if description is the same
    //if ( description.equal(((PassengerCompartment*)other_object)->get_description) )
    if ( description.equal(other_object) )
    {
        //check id
        if ( Object::equal(other_object) )
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
}


///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
PassengerCompartment::PassengerCompartment(const String& description_given) : PlaneComponent(description_given)
{
    inner_PassengerCompartment = NULL;
    cout << "PassengerCompartment just created!" << endl;
    //float random = ((float)rand())/(float)(RAND_MAX);
    //if ( random >= 0.5 )
    //{
    //  String inner_result("Inner: ");
    //  inner_result.concat(description_given);
    //  inner_PassengerCompartment = new PassengerCompartment(inner_result, true);
    //}
}


PassengerCompartment::PassengerCompartment(const PassengerCompartment& given) : PlaneComponent(given)
{
    if (given.inner_PassengerCompartment != NULL )
    {//if the given PassengerCompartment has an inner PassengerCompartment, copy that, too
        inner_PassengerCompartment = new PassengerCompartment(*(given.inner_PassengerCompartment), true);
        std::cout << "Inner PassengerCompartment just created!" << std::endl;
    }
    else
        inner_PassengerCompartment = NULL;
    std::cout << "PassengerCompartment just created!" << std::endl;
}


PassengerCompartment::PassengerCompartment(const String& description_given, bool for_innerPC) : PlaneComponent(description_given)
{
    static bool already_allocated_inner_space = false;
    if ( !already_allocated_inner_space )
    {
        inner_PassengerCompartment = NULL;
        already_allocated_inner_space = true;
    }
}


PassengerCompartment::PassengerCompartment(const PassengerCompartment& given, bool for_innerPC) : PlaneComponent(given)
{
    inner_PassengerCompartment = NULL;
}


PassengerCompartment::~PassengerCompartment(void)
{
    static bool did_it = false;
    if ( !did_it )
    {
        if ( inner_PassengerCompartment != NULL )
        {
            did_it = true;
            delete inner_PassengerCompartment;
            inner_PassengerCompartment = NULL;
            cout << "Inner Passenger Compartment to be destroyed!" << endl;
        }
        cout << "Passenger Compartment to be destroyed!" << endl;
        did_it = false;
    }
}


////////////////////////////////////////////
/*void PassengerCompartment::more_space(const String& inner_description)
{
    static bool have_added_space = false;
    if (!have_added_space)
    {
        float random = ((float)rand())/(float)(RAND_MAX);
        if ( random >= 0.5 )
        {
            inner_PassengerCompartment = new PassengerCompartment(inner_description);
        }
        have_added_space = true;
    }   
}*///////writen a copy constructor instead!!

String PassengerCompartment::toString(void) const
{
    ostringstream resultstream; 
    resultstream << "This is a Passenger Compartment with description: \"";
    resultstream << get_description().get_string(); 
    resultstream << "\" and id: " << Object::get_id();
    resultstream << endl;
    if ( inner_PassengerCompartment == NULL)
        resultstream << "With no inner Passenger Compartment";
    else
    {
        resultstream << "With an inner Passenger Compartment with description: \"";
        resultstream << inner_PassengerCompartment->get_description().get_string();
        resultstream << "\" and id:" << ((Object*)inner_PassengerCompartment)->get_id();
    }
    String result( resultstream.str() );
    return result;
}


void PassengerCompartment::ready_check(void)
{
    cout << "Description of Passenger Compartment:" << endl;
    get_description().print();  
    cout << "Passenger Compartment OK!" << endl;
    if ( inner_PassengerCompartment != NULL )
    {
        cout << "Description of Inner Passenger Compartment:" << endl;
        inner_PassengerCompartment->get_description().print();
        cout << "Inner Passenger Compartment OK!" << endl;
    }
}


Object* PassengerCompartment::clone(void) const
{
    cout << "_______________PassengerCompartment::Clone_______________" << endl;
    return new PassengerCompartment(*this);
}


////////////////////////////////////////////
PassengerCompartment* PassengerCompartment::get_inner_PassengerCompartment(void)
{
    return inner_PassengerCompartment;
}


bool PassengerCompartment::equal(const Object* other_object) const
{
    bool result = false;
    //if there is an inner compartment check if equal
    if ( inner_PassengerCompartment != NULL )
    {   /*//manually check for it's description and ID to avoid recursion
        if ( get_description() == ((PlaneComponent*)other_object)->get_description() )
        {   //check IDs
            if ( get_id() == other_object->get_id() )
                    result = true;
            else    result = false;
        }
        else result = false;*/
        if ( inner_PassengerCompartment->PlaneComponent::equal( ((PassengerCompartment*)other_object)->inner_PassengerCompartment ) )
                result = true;
        else    result = false;
    }

    this->get_description().print();
    dynamic_cast<const PassengerCompartment*>(other_object)->get_description().print();
    cout << "------------------" << endl;
    cout << "------------------" << endl;

    //check for the passenger compartment itself
    if ( PlaneComponent::equal(other_object) )
        result = true;
    else    
        result = false;
    return result;
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
    //seed rand
    srand( (unsigned int) (time(NULL)) );


    String anew("A Class");
    PassengerCompartment test(anew);


    Object* ptr = test.clone();

    cout << "THIS ID: " << test.get_id() << endl;
    cout << "OTHER OBJECT ID:" << ptr->get_id() << endl;
    if (test.equal(&test))
    {
        cout << "Equal" << endl;
    }
    else cout << "Not Equal" << endl;


    cout << "-------------------Exiting main!----------------" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Finally, be sure to clean up the resources you allocate. cloned objects should be deleted at some point, but better if you use something like shared_ptr (from Boost or C++11).

One last note: judging by the amount of output you have sprawled all over the code, I'm guessing you don't know how to use a debugger yet. I can't recommend strongly enough that you learn this. A lot of your frustrations can go away and you don't have to feel like you're coding in the dark if you can learn how to step through your code with the debugger and look at various states in between execution.

Comment: Indeed, it's bad when you code being tired :/  

About B, what I wanted is to get the description of the   PlaneComponent (other_object) but I was passing something completely  
wrong to String::equal. I wanted to compare the 2 description   datamembers and I did this:  
`description.equal (other_object)`   
I was passing the other_object and not the `((PlaneComponent*)other_object)->get_description();`  
This was the main mistake I made.

About C, now that I am passing this:
`&((PlaneComponent*)other_object)->get_description();`

Comment: Which is a String*, this line:  
 `if ( the_string == ((String*)other_object)->the_string)`  
works just fine, because description is a String.  

About the rest of the problems that you've mentioned:  
What I am doing wrong is that I pass an argument as a const, but I don't set the method as a const, right?  
So when having a const argument at a method, I should define this method as a const?  
And when I don't want a method to modify "this" pointer or anything passed as an argument I should define it as const?

Comment: I would delete the ptr (but would do it after testing all the other methods of PassengerCompartment).
What is a shared_ptr? (I am a 2nd year prograduade student and we are just learning OOP using C++).


I just wanted to isolate the printings done by the method I was calling, as they have requested as to print everything that is constructed "Object constructed" etc. I am using gdb and Netbeans helps a lot with steping as it's more eye-friendly.


Thank you very much for the help!:)

Comment: @Chris a shared_ptr is a type of smart pointer (a class that stores a pointer to to allocated memory that you don't have to manually free/delete since it will be done automatically be the destructor) It's built into C++11 and provided through boost for former versions. For now it might be beyond the scope of your immediate studies; universities tend to focus more on theory than practical aspects of a language or compiler (ex: debugger), but it'd be a good idea to look into some of these things for yourself. Especially here, I think the debugger will help you so much.

Comment: @Chris as an easy way to think of it, a member function (method) defined as read-only (const) is one that states that it is not going to be changing any of its member variables (except for ones declared as mutables). For example, the equal method just checks to see if the object is equal to something else: that's not going to be changing the state of the object, so it should be marked as const. A function parameter defined as const means that parameter is not going be changed inside the function. You can find out more on this subject by looking up C++ const-correctness.

Comment: I've used gdb a lot and worked with stepping. Also, this semester, I started using valgrind as well! So by declaring a shared_ptr we can be sure that our allocated data will be freed. Something like a garbage collector?
____
So, in similar cases, the function parameter should be a const(so it won't be altered) and also if the method is just printing or not "writing" to our datamembers we declare it const, as well. Thank you for helping me clearing this out!

Answer (score 1):

```
(gdb) print *this
$1 = {<Object> = {_vptr.Object = 0x804bfa8, id = 1}, the_string = {static npos = 4294967295, 
_M_dataplus = {<std::allocator<char>> = {<__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<char>> = {<No data fields>}, <No data fields>}, _M_p = 0x804f014 "A Class"}}}

(gdb) print *other_object 
$2 = {_vptr.Object = 0x804bf68, id = 2}
```

From the vptrs, you can see that the other object is not a `String`, therefore, the cast in this line

```
cout << ((String*)other_object)->get_string() << endl;
```

is likely illegal.

> Maybe the copy constructors?

Maybe. Maybe, it could be the `equals` method.

- post more code, especially the `equals` method (for all classes), and maybe the copy ctor as well
- check what type is the other object. `print /a 0x804bf68` should give you a hint

Edit:

From the code you posted, I think this line

```
    if ( description.equal(other_object) )
```

in `PlaneComponent::equal` should be

```
    if ( description.equal(((PassengerCompartment*)other_object)->get_description()) )
```

Note that you should check in all of your `equals` methods that the other object is of the corresponding type (lest be surprised when they aren't).

Comment: I tried what you said with print /a address and got this: `(gdb) p *this
$4 = {<Object> = {_vptr.Object = 0x403570, id = 1}, the_string = {static npos = <optimized out>, 
    _M_dataplus = {<std::allocator<char>> = {<__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<char>> = {<No data fields>}, <No data fields>}, _M_p = 0x606028 "A Class"}}}
(gdb) p *other_object 
$5 = {_vptr.Object = 0x4034f0, id = 2}
(gdb) print /a 0x4034f0
$6 = 0x4034f0 <_ZTV20PassengerCompartment+16>
`. So it is a passengercompartment? This is the code you've asked http://pastebin.com/aLLAmACd ! (will add the link to the question as well!

Comment: @Chris: see edit. t will be something like passengercompartment (I'm puzzeld by the `+16`)

Comment: I got this compilation error: `objects.cpp: In member function ‘virtual bool PlaneComponent::equal(const Object*)’:
objects.cpp:193:79: error: no matching function for call to ‘String::equal(<unresolved overloaded function type>)’
objects.cpp:193:79: note: candidate is:
objects.cpp:123:6: note: virtual bool String::equal(const Object*)
objects.cpp:123:6: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘<unresolved overloaded function type>’ to ‘const Object*’`. I think that the problem might be laying in this line, but the argument passed to String::equal should be of type Object*.

Comment: I do check if the objects (this and other_object pointers are the same by printing them) if that's what you mean.

Comment: Just noticed this: "(I'm puzzeld by the +16)". I don't know either :/ as I haven't used this command of gdb `print /a hex_address` until now. :S

Comment: All in all, the problem was the edit that you've posted :) only needed to get the & of it ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you replace

```
cout << ((String*)other_object)->get_string() << endl;
```

with this:

```
cout << dynamic_cast<const String&>(*other_object).get_string() << endl;
```

then the program will end with an exception, that should point you to where the real problem is (probably you are casting an object that is not a specialization of String)

Note: String::get_string() must be **const**

```
class String
{
public:
  // ....
  std::string get_string() const { /*...*/ };
};
```

Note2:

**you are not returning from PlaneComponent::equal** in the case where the descriptions are equal

```
//check if description is the same
if ( description.equal(other_object) )
{
  //check id
  if ( Object::equal(other_object) )
    return true;
  else
    return false;
}
return false; // <<< this is missing
```

Comment: Tried doing that and got this: `In member function ‘virtual bool String::equal(const Object*)’: cannot dynamic_cast ‘other_object’ (of type ‘const class Object*’) to type ‘class String*’ (conversion casts away constness)`, is there any way to bypass this without changing the argument const Object* ?

Comment: Tried it Gigi and got this compilation error: `objects.cpp: In member function ‘virtual bool String::equal(const Object*)’:
objects.cpp:129:64: error: passing ‘const String’ as ‘this’ argument of ‘std::string String::get_string()’ discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]`. What should I do? :S

Comment: make the String::get_string() method const

Comment: Worked :) I got this: `terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_cast'
  what():  std::bad_cast

Program received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
0x00007ffff75563a5 in __GI_raise (sig=6) at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:64
64 ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c: No such file or directory.
 in ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c`

Comment: good! now step in with gdb and catch that bug! (the object is not a string)

Comment: So the problem is with the copy constructors? (as clone method is calling the copy constructor of PlaneComponent)

Comment: wait... is PlaneComponent also a String?

Comment: PlaneComponent has a datamember that is a String (String description). The problem is that in PassengerCompartment::equal and PlaneComponent::equal I print the Objects and see that the other_object is a PassengerCompartment. (maybe it's the way I'm calling String::equal?)

Comment: somewhat founded it... you are not returning from PlaneComponent::equal in case when the description is not the same

Comment: Thank you, Gigi, just added that, but still the segfault keeps coming up. :/